# How to use case statement properly? How to use case statement with where or join table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to replace the display value for all password1 = 1 by name1 and password2 = 1 by name 2 without changing the actual value in database. But When I executed the code, the system return:

"Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Order'."

Output I have:

---

- **name1, name2,   GateCode, password1, password2, state**

  ---
- Ryan, Lisa, 1, 3214, 4564, FL
- Brandon,    Joan,    2,           5324,       1,          NV
- Leo,        Ben,     3,           1   ,       1,          WA

  ---

Output I want

---

- **name1, name2,   GateCode, password1, password2, state**

  ---
- Ryan, Lisa, 1, 3214, 4564, FL
- Brandon,    Joan,    2,           5324,       Joan,         NV
- Leo,        Ben,     3,           Leo ,      Ben,         WA

  ---

Here is my code:

```
Select Top 10 
   g.name1 as 'name1'
 , g.name1 as 'name2'
 , c.gateCode as GateCode
 , c.pas1 as 'password1'
 , c.pas2 as 'password2'
 , g.state as 'state'
from guest g
     Left code c
     on g.guest_cdoe = c.guest_code 
Where 
  CASE 
      WHEN password1 = 1 and g.guest_cdoe = c.guest_code
      Then ba.bank_name1
      WHEN password2 = 2 and g.guest_cdoe = c.guest_code
      Then ba.bank_name1
  End
Order by 3
```

Comment: so I guess there was a typo in the naming of guest.guest_cdoe?  Ya might want to fix that.

Comment: You should avoid ordering by ordinal position. It is a bad habit to develop. If you, or somebody else, comes along and changes the order of the select statement your output will be in the wrong order. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx (Look at the best practices sections). Or this one: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Comment: @Hogan, Thank you. I fixed that already after fixing the script.

Comment: @Sean Thank you for the article. Good point.

Comment: @Hogan, Is it necessary to have g.guest_code =c.guest_code on the case statement in my case? The output is the same w and w/o g.guest_code = c.guest_code. But which way is better?

Comment: @baciyan - The output can be different.  You are doing a left join; this checks to make sure there was an element in the code table.  You could also say `g.guest_code is not null` instead of `g.guest_cdoe = c.guest_code` if this is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want... it is hard to tell but should point you in the right direction.  You want the case in the select statement not the where statement.

```
Select Top 10 
   g.name1 as 'name1'
 , g.name2 as 'name2'
 , c.gateCode as GateCode
 , CASE 
      WHEN c.pas1 = 1 and g.guest_cdoe = c.guest_code
      THEN g.name1 
      ELSE c.pas1
   END
 , CASE 
      WHEN c.pas2 = 1 and g.guest_cdoe = c.guest_code
      THEN g.name2 
      ELSE c.pas2
   END
 , g.state as 'state'
from guest g
     Left code c
     on g.guest_cdoe = c.guest_code 
Order by 3
```

Comment: Thank you Hogan. That works! could you explain why I should include Case statement in select statement instead of where clause? Could I include it in join statement? Like Left join code c On Case When...End

Comment: @baciyan you can use it in a where clause and a join statement.  but it did not make sense to do so in this case -- in this case you wanted to change what was selected based on a row by row criteria so it belonged in the select statement.  If you wanted to change if you filtered something then it would be in the where, if you wanted to change how you joined then it would be in the join.